# Postman variable refresh: dynamic update the id variable

Tags: variables, postman

I want to stop copying and pasting the new taskId I get when I make a new post. So that I can easily use other endpoints with that Id and not update all of my paths manually, I know I can update the variable in the folder and use it there, but there must be another option.

[image]

Comment: For more information: https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-collection-variables-in-scripts

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("taskId", pm.response.json().id);
```

Add this to the Tests panel of your post request.

[image]

Note that this can technically be used to **refresh any variable**. So if you are using a variable to set your **auth token** you can add a script similar to this to the endpoint that gets the token.